# Keep 2 instances of SQL Server synced

Tags: sql-server, replication, mirroring, sql-server-2019, windows-server-2019

We want to set up a second instance/server of SQL Server such that both instances will be kept in sync. The reason is we need to separate some users and processes out to a separate server for business reasons.

More information (requested in comments):

- Neither instance would be read-only
- It does not need to be synced in realtime, but that would be nice
- We have full control of the table schemas

We've done a lot of research, but most potential options are part of disaster recovery features, so we're not sure if those are right for this.

I'm not sure how to whittle down this list without actually trying the different options, but that would be very time consuming. If there's an option I'm missing, that would be very helpful.

[Always On Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)
[Merge Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/merge/merge-replication?view=sql-server-ver15)
[Database Mirroring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/database-mirroring/database-mirroring-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)
[Synchronize Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/synchronize-data?view=sql-server-ver15)
[Windows Server Failover Clustering with SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/windows-server-failover-clustering-wsfc-with-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) (Is this what is normally meant by clustering?)

Comment: No, there is nothing that will do this based on the load.  Newer availability groups will round robin with multiple replicas, but round robin does not take into account load.  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171438/load-balancing-reads-sql-server-2016-ag

Comment: Round robin may good enough. You like Always On Availability Groups as a solution for this?

Comment: The term you're looking for is "load balancer".

Comment: The main goal is to keep these 2 servers synced up. Load balancing would be nice to have.

Comment: If you have the technical expertise to handle clusters and availability groups, then yes, I like it.  If you don't have anyone that's ever used clusters, and nobody that's touched availability groups, then maybe not.  If you use an alias for readers to connect to, you could use DNS to round robin connections, but not queries, using replication.  You can't read from a mirroring secondary, and mirroring is being deprecated, so wouldn't advise that.

Comment: Windows Server Failover Clustering, at least they way I've always used it, is for failover, and not for load balancing. That is, only one server/instance is running at a time, but they can each see the same set of .mdf and .ldf files. So it mainly protects you from hardware failures, like power supplies, CPUs, RAM, and NICs. (But virtual machines on clustered hosts can do that, better, with fewer hassles.) So I don't think WSFC is going to meet your needs.

Comment: If you're prepared to change the application CosmosDB and other "new SQL" products may work.

Comment: Question has been clarified by removing excess information. Can it be reopened?

Comment: I don't know that the clarification helps. The question is still rather open-ended. You want a second instance, and you mention that you are already aware of the various mechanisms that SQL provides. But without knowing why you want such a second copy (other than indicating that it is not for disaster recovery), I don't know what anyone can tell you.

Comment: @DougDeden Thank you, I added the reason: "we need to separate some users and processes out to a separate server".

Comment: Why do you need to seperate some users and processes? What edition of SQL Server do you use?  Is the second copy read-only?  Does it need to be updated in near-realtime?  Can you modify the table schema in the database if needed? Can you instead use the workload isolation features of a single instance (RCSI,Resource Governor, Secondary Columnstore Indexes)?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft We would use Resource Governor if we can't figure out how to use a second server. We are using SQL Server 2019 (per the tags). Answers to your other questions added to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Can you guarantee that the data changes on the two replicas would never conflict?  Or do you need to be able to apply a policy to merge conflicting changes?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft It would be difficult to guarantee but not impossible. It would take a lot of effort, though.

Comment: I’ve nominated the question for reopening, but based on your additional information Merge Replication may be your only option.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft It doesn't look like it got opened up, and there are no new comments saying what needs to be addressed to open it back up. I've been a StackExchange user for a long time but can't find an up-to-date guide on what to do about this.

Comment: Well, then write a new question.  Detail _exactly_ what is driving the desire to separate the databases.  IE "separate some users and processes out to a separate server for business reasons" is not nearly specific enough.  Who are the different users? What are the processes you want to segregate?   What are the business reasons?  What are the characteristics of the workload?  What Edition of SQL Server are you using? Whether to do so is more important than how.  And that will differentiate this closed question from your new one.